# In MySQL what's the correct way to map a "belongs-to" relationship when an item could belong to two or more types of item?

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many, relationships

If this is standard knowledge, I apologize. Part of my problem is I'm not even sure what language to use to search.

If I have the tables Event, Department, Client and I want to denote a one-to-many relationship between Clients and Events but also between Departments and Events, what would I do?

If I had a one-to-many relationship with Clients to Events only, I'd simply have a client_id field in Event. I could have two columns: client_id and department_id, but is there a better approach or can you point me at resources or even proper terminology so I can find more and educate myself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By the RDBMS system, what you have is the best approach.

You would have a client_id column and a department_id column in the events table, which maps to a key in a client and department table respectively.

Edit: However, if you have a ton of data, and you have abundant storage space and would like to optimize for speed of operations, you might consider joining the columns of one or both of the tables to the events table. Storage is cheap nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Standard normalization is to have "membership" tables that are join tables.

Your tables then become:

- Event (event_id)
- Client (client_id)
- Department (department_id)

Plus:

- Client_Events (id, client_id, event_id)
- Department_Events (id, department_id, event_id)

Then using `JOIN`, you can get what you want. MySQL/Postgre can handle `JOIN`s of this sort very quickly.